# when gray image width is 2048, 4096, running time of rotate 90 image is more longer than nearby

Tags: image, opencv, rotation

Now I am going to rotate image 90 degrees, the code is below, using openCV Mat struct. 
And I found a phenomenon that when the image width is 4096 ,running time is about twice of running time of image width is 4097. Following is the running time output. Does somebody Know why?

```
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include "opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;
void main()
{
std::string ImageFileName0 = "F:\\temp\\4096-3000.bmp";
std::string ImageFileName1 = "F:\\temp\\4097-3000.bmp";

Mat image4096 = imread(ImageFileName0);
Mat image4097 = imread(ImageFileName1);

int lWidth4096 = image4096.size().width;
int lHeight4096 = image4096.size().height;
Mat image4096Res(lWidth4096, lHeight4096, CV_8UC1);
for (int i=0; i<lHeight4096; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<lWidth4096;j++)
    {
        image4096Res.at<uchar>(j, i) = 0;
    }
}

int lWidth4097 = image4097.size().width;
int lHeight4097 = image4097.size().height;
Mat image4097Res(lWidth4097, lHeight4097, CV_8UC1);
for (int i = 0; i < lHeight4097; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < lWidth4097; j++)
    {
        image4097Res.at<uchar>(j, i) = 0;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    double time0 = static_cast<double>(getTickCount());
    for (int j = 0; j < lWidth4096; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<lHeight4096; ++i)
        {
            image4096Res.at<uchar>(j, i) = image4096.at<uchar>(i, j);
        }
    }
    double time4096 = (static_cast<double>(getTickCount()) - time0) / getTickFrequency();

    double time1 = static_cast<double>(getTickCount());
    for (int j = 0; j < lWidth4097; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<lHeight4097; ++i)
        {
            //srcTmp = srcimage.PointToRow(i);
            //*(dstTmp + i) = srcimage.GetPixelValue(j, i);
            image4097Res.at<uchar>(j, i) = image4097.at<uchar>(i, j);

        }
    }
    double time4097 = (static_cast<double>(getTickCount()) - time1) / getTickFrequency();
    std::cout << "4096 time:" << time4096*1000 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4097 time:" << time4097*1000 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
namedWindow("aa",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("aa", image4096Res);

waitKey();
}
```

Running time result:

4096 time:149.337

4097 time:56.8092

4096 time:143.556

4097 time:67.4758

4096 time:142.07

4097 time:58.2825

4096 time:153.973

4097 time:57.1894

4096 time:145.086

4097 time:58.7944

4096 time:156.33

4097 time:87.9404

4096 time:140.224

4097 time:56.9525

4096 time:144.413

4097 time:57.133

4096 time:141.672

4097 time:54.916

4096 time:148.443

4097 time:55.8449

[Time consuming varies with the width of the image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr6Eu.png)

It is clear that only when the image width is 1024,2048,4096 the execute time is abnormal, while the overall trend is increasing linearly.

Comment: What CPU? IMHO this smells of cache contention, due to the row length being a high power of 2, causing them to be spaced at a critical stride. | Anyway, I guess this is an excercise. Normally you'd use a combination of `cv::transpose` and `cv::flip`, or if you have new enough version of OpenCV, `cv::rotate`.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks for replying. My Computer CPU is Intel Core i7 5500U@2.40GHz.  | Yes, this is an excercise. I want to write a transpose code myself. And I have already reference the transpose API of OpenCV, however its performance is also like this. What I am confused is that, when I call the transpose function of OpenCV by the dll, everything is alright.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using this version to see if the same difference exist
Also added test to see if loaded image is of type CV_8UC1.
Be aware that the result of your and my solution is a **mirrored** image

```
int lWidth4096 = image4096.size().width;
int lHeight4096 = image4096.size().height;
Mat image4096Res = cv::Mat::zeros(lWidth4096, lHeight4096, CV_8UC1);

int lWidth4097 = image4097.size().width;
int lHeight4097 = image4097.size().height;
Mat image4097Res = cv::Mat::zeros(lWidth4097, lHeight4097, CV_8UC1);

if (image4096.type() != CV_8UC1)
    throw "need 8bit image as input";

if (image4097.type() != CV_8UC1)
    throw "need 8bit image as input";

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    double time0 = static_cast<double>(getTickCount());
    for (int j = 0; j < lWidth4096; ++j)
    {
        uint8_t *buf = image4096Res.ptr(j);
        for (int i = 0; i<lHeight4096; ++i)
        {
            //image4096Res.at<uchar>(j, i) = image4096.at<uchar>(i, j);
            //buf[i] = image4096.at<uchar>(i, j);
            buf[i] = (image4096.data + image4096.step[0] * i)[j];
        }
    }
    double time4096 = (static_cast<double>(getTickCount()) - time0) / getTickFrequency();

    double time1 = static_cast<double>(getTickCount());
    for (int j = 0; j < lWidth4097; ++j)
    {
        uint8_t *buf = image4097Res.ptr(j);
        for (int i = 0; i<lHeight4097; ++i)
        {
            //image4097Res.at<uchar>(j, i) = image4097.at<uchar>(i, j);
            //buf[i] = image4097.at<uchar>(i, j);
            buf[i] = (image4097.data + image4097.step[0] * i)[j];
        }
    }
    double time4097 = (static_cast<double>(getTickCount()) - time1) / getTickFrequency();
    std::cout << "4096 time:" << time4096 * 1000 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4097 time:" << time4097 * 1000 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```